# Account Disabled and Information Wrong?

Tags: itunes, email

So today I went to buy something on the itunes store, but it said that I had to change my password since the account is pretty old. I did that, then tried to log in again, but it said my password was wrong. I kept entering it in and eventually my account got disabled. To disable it I have to enter security questions that I never set, and enter in my birthday, which apple constantly says is wrong. I click on the email option, but no email comes in to the recovery email that I set up. Please help!

Comment: Did you receive email from Apple after changing the password ?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to call Apple Support. Just go to [the Apple ID support page](http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/) and enter the information as it affects you. (I think going to "Apple ID" -> "Disabled Apple ID" would suit you best). I recommend calling telephone support, but you can also email them like suggested. Either way, it would be best to have a device connected to that ID.

Comment: Seconded! If you haven't looked at your account online in years, you won't have any questions set, nor  DOB recorded. At that point, there's no way past. Apple phone support have sorted that out for me in the past within minutes.